# install tensorflow from source code, cuda9.1, cuDNN7.0.5, libcublas.so.9.1 not found

Tags: tensorflow

ERROR: /home/kenny/Downloads/tensorflow-1.5.0-rc1/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/BUILD:326:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco' failed (Exit 1)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcublas.so.9.1, needed by bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

Answer (score 1):

Check this issue comment 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15656#issuecomment-362104182

The current version of TensorFlow (1.7) does not support CUDA9.1, but you should have several options:

1. Downgrade to CUDA 9.0
2. Compile TensorFlow from the source code by your own
3. Find an existing whl file for you (unofficial release).  ex. I fixed the issue by using a whl from https://github.com/mind/wheels
4. Wait until Tensorflow supports CUDA9.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install Cuda 9.1 from Nvidia as a prerequisite to building from source.

Comment: I did install Cuda9.1 before building tensorflow from source.

Comment: The tensorflow build may not know where the cuda libraries actually are located, or rather looking in a different spot, than where they are on your machine. First step: find where the libcublas.so file is on your machine

Comment: LD_LIRBRARY is set properly, do you know where else?

Comment: No, it depends a lot on your setup.  And I believe it’s LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  You’ll just have to follow the build scripts provided and debug them.  Or just use the prebuilt version, which I believe is recommended anyway

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue. Probably adding this flag `--action_env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"` in your `bazel build` command will solve the issue. Make sure you have set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` or wherever your cuda toolkit installation is present.

EDIT: In case setting up environment variable doesn't work. You can further try by running `sudo ldconfig -v|grep 'libcublas.so.9.1'`. In my case cuda's version is 9.1 hence I verify for the same. If `grep` doesn't return the expected library, just try other ways to register your path to `ldconfig`

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird dynamic link lib error.

Somehow bazel doesn't recognize LD_CONFIG. You'll have to manually update the /etc/ld.so.conf (in my case with Ubuntu 17.1, the config files are in /etc/ld.so.conf.d), and add a line that points to the /usr/local/cuda/lib64 folder.

Then run
    sudo ldconfig
to re-build the ld cache. You can verify that the cuda libs are in the search folders by 
    sudo ldconfig -v | grep cuda
The build should work now.